# Access albums of friends using Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to access albums of my friends.

According to changelogs of v2.1 it is now not possible to retrieve full friendlist but there are apps In android playstore which can download  album of friends.  How are they doing it?

Answer (score 2):

They are probably using an App created before April 30th, 2014 - so they can still use v1.0, but only until end of April 2015. Apps created after April 2014 can only use v2.0+ and are not able to get all friends anymore and friend permissions have been removed too.

See changelog for all the dates: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog